# change a td change all the column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

I have to disable a input in a `td`, based in the selection in the `td` select, the `td` target is the next one, but when I select a option it changes all the next `td` in the column. I´m new in this u_u

```
<table id="tabla">
<!-- Cabecera de la tabla -->
   thead>
     <tr>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Apellidos</th>
    <th>Sexo</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="especial">
        <select id="mySelect" onchange="funcSelect()" name="inmueble_psesion" class="browser-default">
                <option value="1">PROPIO</option>
                <option value="2">RENTADO</option>
                <option value="3">COMODATO</option>
                <option value="4">*OTRO</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" disabled></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" value="3" ></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="especial">
        <select id="mySelect2" onchange="funcSelect()" 
        name="inmueble_psesion" class="browser-default">
                <option value="1">PROPIO</option>
                <option value="2">RENTADO</option>
                <option value="3">COMODATO</option>
                <option value="4">*OTRO</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" disabled></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" value=""></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" value=""></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

this is the function I call for disable the next input, basically i am obtaining the id and the value and depending on that I disable the input, but apparently I disable or enable all the td's not just the one in the row I work

```
function funcSelect(){
  var idSel = $("select").attr("id");
  console.log(idSel);
  var valSel = $("#"+idSel).val();
  var id = "#"+idSel;
  console.log(id);
  console.log(valSel);
  if(valSel === "4"){
    $("td.especial").next("td").children().removeAttr("disabled");
  }else{
    $("td.especial").next("td").children().attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript doesn't work this way.Here is a working version of you code..... Plus you don't have to use any inline function to get this work.....

```
HTML: 

 <table id="tabla">
  <!-- Cabecera de la tabla -->
       <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Apellidos</th>
    <th>Sexo</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td class="especial">
    <select id="mySelect" name="inmueble_psesion" class="browser-default">
            <option value="1">PROPIO</option>
            <option value="2">RENTADO</option>
            <option value="3">COMODATO</option>
            <option value="4">*OTRO</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td><input type="text" name="" disabled></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="" value="3" ></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="especial">
    <select id="mySelect2"
    name="inmueble_psesion" class="browser-default">
            <option value="1">PROPIO</option>
            <option value="2">RENTADO</option>
            <option value="3">COMODATO</option>
            <option value="4">*OTRO</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td><input type="text" name="" disabled></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="" value=""></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="" value=""></td>
</tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript/Jquery:

```
 $(document).on('change', 'select', function(event) {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val == 4) {
        $(this).parent().next('td').children().removeAttr('disabled');
    }else{
        $(this).parent().next('td').children().attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

Comment: sooo much thanks! it work and is clean and elegant!,  i have to much to learn, really thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$("#"+idSel).closest("td.especial")` instead of `$("td.especial")` to find just the first ancestor matching `td.especial` selector.

Your current code is just matching everything existing in DOM matching given selector `td.especial.

Comment: ok thanks, with that it changes the next input only in the first tr, but in the next tr dont do anything when i change the select u_u